# Getting img urls and put it on for loop

Tags: javascript, image, for-loop, fetch

**I can get the values of grade and iconPath(url pic). The problem is on for loop, all the picture(url picture) print on 1 card, Anyone can help me how to print images in different card. Thank you **

```
 document.getElementById('cardinfo').innerHTML += 
          `<div class="card">
            <div class="card-front">
             <div class="image-container">
              <img class="img-flip" src="image/class-arbalist.png"/></br>
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-back">
            <div class="image-container" id="img-link">
            `
            for (var i = 0; i < grad.length; i++) {
              var grade = data.data.inven[i].grade;
              var grade1;
              if (grade == 4 ){
                var iconPath = data.data.inven[i].iconPath;
                document.getElementById('img-link').innerHTML +=`
                <img class="img-skill2" src="${iconPath}"/>`
              }else if(grade == 5){
                var iconPath = data.data.inven[i].iconPath;
                document.getElementById('img-link').innerHTML +=`
                <img class="img-skill3" src="${iconPath}"/>`
              }else{
  
              }
            }
            `
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>`
          ;
```

[Card. Only first card got all the images not the second card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlpEq.png)

**Anyone can help me how to put output images(urlpic) in different cards. Thank you **

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful if you included a jsfiddle with your CSS so we can get a better idea of what this is supposed to look like.  My first thought is that you aren't creating more 'card' or 'card-back' divs in your loop, you are just continuously appending an <img> to the same div with id "image-link" over and over again

Comment: oh, that is my problem. All the images of the imglink print on just 1 card, but the other card has no image. Should I make new div for more card?

Comment: I edited and put a picture of sample,

Comment: What do you mean "on different cards"?  Can you show how you would like it to look?

Comment: @ckesplin I uploaded a picture below the code. All the pictures are posted at the first card and the second card have none. How to put the img src url in both cards?

Comment: @fordat oh, that is my problem. All the images of the imglink print on just 1 card, but the other card has no image. Should I make new div for more card?